# WCS layer save postgis

Tags: postgis, layers, wcs, isric

I have an external WCS layer

> ```
> https://maps.isric.org/mapserv?map=/map/nitrogen.map&
> SERVICE=WCS&
> VERSION=2.0.0&
> REQUEST=DescribeCoverage&
> COVERAGEID=nitrogen_5-15cm_Q0.5
> ```

that comes from an external data service, so I would like to save it in the postgis database so that I can then overlay the polygons on it and make graphic intersections to determine the type of soil on which the polygon is located respectively

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: I haven't tried anything because I don't know where to start

Comment: You just need to download the data, I assume GeoTIFF will be best for your use, probably in a series of GetCoverage requests, then use raster2pgsql to load.  See https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/34408/loading-geotiffs-into-postgis-using-raster2pgsql